# Breakline in Paragraph Reportlab

Tags: python, html, reportlab

I am trying to add a breakline in Paragraph in Reportlab. While some HTML tags like  works, 
 causes this exception:

```
caused exception paraparser: syntax error: No content allowed in br tag
```

This is where I wrap my text:

```
  style = ParagraphStyle(
      name='Normal',
      spaceAfter=40,
      fontName='Times-BoldItalic',
      fontSize=18,
  )

text=Paragraph(f"<p> <b>{df.set_index('concat').loc[i]['Title']}</b> <br> Some more text </p>", style=style)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<br/>` instead of `<br>`.

Using `<br>` raises a `ValueError: paraparser: syntax error: No content allowed in br tag`

---

If using `<br/>` does not fix the issue then use a closing tag `<br/>` along with `<br>`.

Try:

```
text=Paragraph(f"<p> <b>{df.set_index('concat').loc[i]['Title']}</b> <br> <br/>Some more text </p>", style=style)
```